# oracle sql pivoting options

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got the a query

which gives the following output

[image]

And here is a sample data. I have marked two rows which contain the same mobile number. I want to do the following if there are same mobile numbers I want to merge the rows into one and its corresponding data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `LISTAGG analytic function` to do that. Good tips about it (and other ways to achieve your result) can be found [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#listagg).

Let my try to sketch a simplified solution. Lets say your query looks like this - I dont like joining in the where clause =)

```
select gsm.mobile_no, sgcp.name as "charge name"
from service.gsm gsm
join charge.gsm_charge_plan sgcp
on sgcp.service_code = gsm.code;
```

Then you could do something like

```
SELECT gsm.mobile_no, 
LISTAGG(sgcp.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sgcp.name) AS "charge names"
from service.gsm gsm
join charge.gsm_charge_plan sgcp
on sgcp.service_code = gsm.code
GROUP BY gsm.mobile_no;
```

Comment: Hi, That's quite nice. But can you put the results in a different column since now it groups them in the same column all??

Comment: @user3017335 That is not possible in general. Just imagine, if one mobile number has 10 rows associated. You would need 10 different "charge name" columns. SQL generally does not support dynamic column count. You would have to look either for a hand coded fixed column count solution or use a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try - Group by gsm.mobile_no ?

Comment: That would be equal to simply dropping the distinctive columns (like "charge name" in the example above). I doubt this is intended.

Comment: Your way is certainly better :)